# PHP/MySQL: Two data input and save into one row in MySQL database

Tags: php

I new in PHP. FOr start, I want to create CRUD. Now I'm doing for 'create'. My database table contains, 'id', 'fullname', 'age', and 'email'.

But at my PHP page, user need to input, 'fname', 'lname', 'age' and 'email'. My question is, how I want to merge 'fname' and 'lname' and save it to table's row 'fullname'.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

include_once("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$fname = $_POST['fname'];   
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($age) || empty($email)) {

      if(empty($fname)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

      if(empty($lname)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Name field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

      if(empty($age)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Age field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

      if(empty($email)) {
        echo "<font color='red'>Email field is empty.</font><br/>";
    }

      echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Go Back</a>";
} else { 

      $sql = "INSERT INTO users(fullname, age, email) VALUES(:fullname, :age, :email)";
      $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

      $query->bindparam(':fullname', $fname,$lname);
      $query->bindparam(':age', $age);
      $query->bindparam(':email', $email);
      $query->execute();
      echo "<font color='green'>Data added successfully.";
      echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>View Result</a>";
}
 }
      ?>
      <html>
      <head>
     <title>Add Data</title>
      </head>

    <body>
   <a href="index.php">Home</a>
   <br/><br/>

   <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
       <table width="25%" border="0">
          <tr> 
          <tr> 
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
          </tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: you could just ask for "name", Afterall not everyone has a first and last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate it (I added a space between first and last name) `$query->bindparam(':fullname', $fname . ' ' . $lname);`

Comment: you answer is correct, but when it save to database, it will save like this. JohnTerry. but i want John Terry

Comment: That's why I added a space `$fname . '  ' . $lname`

Answer (score 0):

You need to chose a parameter name then concatenate to that.

```
$query->bindparam(':fullname', $full);
$full = $fname . ' ' . $lname;
```

Additionally you'll need to change `:fullnamename` in the query to be `:fullname` otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Or change the name in the `bindparam`... (which should be `bindParam`)

Comment: @Nick True, either or, but they need to match. Functions aren't case sensitive so either should work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the case insensitivity, but I keep (stupidly?) expecting they will eventually fix that and I'd rather have the code correct to begin with.

Comment: @Nick but then they'd have to pick a naming convention for their functions :)

Comment: you answer is correct, but when it save to database, it will save like this. JohnTerry. but i want John Terry

Comment: @Memen Add a space in that case. The `bindparam` function requires a parameter, not a value. I'll make an update showing it with the space.